# Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '[API.Posters.Items]'

Tags: swift, types, enums

I am trying to pass data from Interactor to Presenter.
In Interactor I have `switch` , where I get result and I want to pass result into my array.

My error is: **Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '[API.Posters.Items]'**

[API.Posters.Items] - is my model

So, I have function:

```
func loadMyRecords(completion: @escaping (Result<MyRecordsContent, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard currentPage != .last else { return }
        
        currentRequest?.cancel()
        
        currentRequest = postersService.fetchRecords(fromRow: currentPage.fromRow, closedOnly: isClosedOnly) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            
            switch result {
            case let .success(rawModel):
                if let placeholder = rawModel.placeholder {
                    self.content = .placeholder(placeholder)
                } else {
                    var currentItems = self.content.item
                    var items = currentItems.append(contentsOf: rawModel.items) **<---ERROR (Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '[API.Posters.Items]')**
                    self.content = .items(items)
                }
                
                self.currentPage = .some(rawModel.nextRow)
                
                completion(.success(self.content))
                
            case let .failure(error):
                self.currentPage = .last
                
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I have enum, where I switch content:

```
enum MyRecordsContent {
    case items([API.Posters.Items])
    case placeholder(API.Placeholder)
    case empty
    var item: [API.Posters.Items] {
        switch self {
        case .placeholder:
            return []
        case let .items(items):
            return items
        case .empty:
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it on this line - `self.content = .items(rawModel.items)`? If so, you mean `rawModel.item`

Comment: @jnpdx I wrote incorrect code. Can you see it now?

Comment: Yes -- did you look at my suggestion?

Comment: @jnpdx if I write 'self.content = .items(rawModel.items)' and comment two upper lines, error is disappear

Comment: I think you have some confusion because of your naming. You have a `case items` and a `var item`, which, ironically, returns an array of items. `item` is `[API.Posters.Items]` and `items` is `MyRecordsContent`. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @jnpdx yes, if I write `var items = currentItems.append(contentsOf: rawModel.item)` I have a mistake: `Value of type 'API.Posters.MyRecordsResponse' has no member 'item'`

Comment: Hm -- that looks like you're trying `.item` on the `response`.